# How to create an accordion of several content query webparts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, content-query-web-part

What I have : On SharePoint Online, three content query webparts which use catalogs. So these webparts display files from other collections.

What I need : that this three webparts become one dynamic accordion.

That is to say, if you click on "Library one" it reduces "Library two" and "Library three". If you click on "Library two", it reduces the others, etc.

Honestly I have no clue on how to do that or if it's even possible. I used some JS before to customize my pages but not so much.

I'm searching for a client-side solution JSOM/JQuery. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option to achieve  this is as follow:

- Create a custom page layout.
- Design your accordion there
- Keep empty webpart zones in the each accordion box.
- Create the page with new page layout.
- Edit the page from browser, and now you will have accordion look and
  you can add your CQWP in the empty webpart zones.

I have done this practically for displaying multiple document library in accordion.

Required tool is just a SharePoint Designer.

Sample I have done:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer, but you're right the other answer seems more simpler for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery UI accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) or [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to create Accordion.

Also, since you want to attach it to a content query web part, you must opt for `Client Side Rendering also known as JSLink`. This will let you define the rendering of your data. Which can be utilized in creating accordion. [Here is a blog explain CSR in details.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

**Edit**

I didnt read you dont want to implement CSR on Content By Query Web Part. So, CSR in not required in you case. Just Add the three web part to web part zone on page. After that, open the `page` tab and click on `edit source`. From there, add the `CDN/SiteAssets` reference to `JQuery and JQuery UI` or `Jquery and Bootstrap`. And finally add the Lable divs and add accordion class name from desired library to other Web part divs.

Comment: This approach is quite more simpler than mine. :-)

Comment: Thankyou. I prefer using some standard JS libraries to simplify work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that and see if it fits my need ! :)